# Message: Unsupported method ('POST'). Error 501 Python

Tags: python-3.x, http, post, server

I am trying to learn some Http Server in an udacity online academy. The thing is that the folllowing code is triggering the error Message: Unsupported method ('POST'). Error 501 Python:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from urllib.parse import parse_qs


class MessageHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        # 1. How long was the message?
        length = int(self.headers.get('Content-length', 0))

        # 2. Read the correct amount of data from the request.
        data = self.rfile.read(length).decode()

        # 3. Extract the "message" field from the request data.
        message = parse_qs(data)["message"][0]

        # Send the "message" field back as the response.
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(message.encode())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MessageHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 3):

Which Python? Your code is correct. Tested it right now, it sends the response.

The only modification I've made is

```
#message = parse_qs(data)["message"][0]
message = 'hello'
```

Client code:

```
import requests
res = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/abc', data = {'key':'value'})
print(res)
```

Client gets `200` response

Comment: Could you please add more information to your answer. I am kind of Rookie and would be cool to have the whole code to know where I am failing

Comment: The fact is that your code is **correct**. I've just posted an example for **client** code to show, how I tested your server. And this all worked

Comment: Thanks a lot grapes :-) But then why is not working and I always get this 501 error without showing what I've written in the HTML?

Comment: Can you tell me how you test your server? What is your client?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience with me. What I am doing is just writing "python -m http.server" in my git bash terminal. I have an HTML file with a text field that when you press send, should show me this text back after doing the request to the mentioned python code. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the name of your python-file? http.server?

Comment: Why `python -m http.server` ?? You have to use `python youre_file.py`

Comment: By typing `python -m http.server` you launch **module** `http.server`. It is not your code. Unless you create setup script and install your server, you cannot launch it with `-m` option

Comment: I love you guys! Now I see it :D